# Is there a function in r that convert frequency from Hz into w (radians)?

Tags: r, signals, signal-processing

I am looking a function that convert frequency from Hz into w (radian)

Matlab has the function 'hz2w'  just wonder if there is an equivalent one in R

I looked at the manual of the 'signal' and  'gsignal' packages but it seems there

is no equivalent

Comment: You can define your own `hz2w = function(f) f * 2 * pi`

Comment: Presumably you are looking for radians per second? b/c otherwise the units are incomparable, aren't they?

Comment: The only Matlab function I can find is [here](https://sail.usc.edu/~lgoldste/Ling582old/Week%205/Assignment5.pdf), where the assignment asks to you to write a function converting cycles per *second* to radians per *sample* (given a sampling rate ...)

Comment: @Ben Bolker I am not doing any assignments, I only convert a Matlab script into R and I come across this function but I could not find in what package is

Comment: that's fine, I'm not accusing you of posting a homework question.  But it would be really helpful (and possibly prevent your question from being closed) if you can tell us **where** you "[came] across this function"; can you edit your question to include a link to where you found it so we can have some more context? (I guess it might be in a random script that's not on the internet anywhere.) In any case, I'm guessing that @GregorThomas's comment answers your question (perhaps they could post it as an answer ...?) (I don't think `hz2w` is a base Matlab function ...)

Comment: @Ben Bolker it's pdf slide from a lecture. I marked Gregor as an answer

Comment: If @GregorThomas doesn't come back and post that comment as an answer, you could post it yourself (that's encouraged).

Answer (score 2):

You can define your own:

```
hz2w = function(f) f * 2 * pi
```